# How can I evaluate this integral with Dirac's delta function?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, dirac-delta

I have the following integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin^{-1}(1/x)\delta'(x^4-1)\, \mathrm{d}x$$
I tried to solve it by using the property $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\delta'(g(x))\, \mathrm{d}x=-\sum_k \frac{f'(c_k)}{|g'(c_k)|}$$ but $f'(1)$ is not defined.

Comment: Why is it not defined? It's only undefined at $0$

Comment: If $f(x)=\sin^{-1}(1/x)$ then $f'(x)=-1/x\sqrt{x^2-1}$ which is not defined at $x=1$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well, if $\sin^{-1}$ stands for $\arcsin$, your integral does not make sense… I mean, $\sin^{-1}(1/x)$ is defined only in $]-\infty , -1] \cup [1, +\infty[ \subset \mathbb{R}$, therefore neither $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \cdots \text{d} x$ nor $\int_0^{+\infty} \cdots \text{d} x$ are well defined.

Comment: I see, thank you